# How to use SAP Gateway for Microsoft without Azure?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sap-gateway

I have a *SharePoint 2013 Server* and a *SAP HANA Server* that both are **on-premises**.

And I have **no Azure**.

Now, I want to integrate these two platform via **SAP Gateway for Microsoft**.

How could I do this? Or does there have any other component that could do this task? Thanks for any advice.